# Extraindo IP de origem e destino para verificar se o servidor se tornou inoperante após ataque

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from scapy.all import *
from collections import deque

def print_attack_measure(pcap_file):
    plist = rdpcap(pcap_file)
    server_ip = "192.168.1.5"
    n = 300
    d = deque(maxlen=n)

    # If you want source/destination IP addresses
    getsrcdst = lambda x:(x.src,x.dst)
    # If you want MAC addresses
    getmacs   = lambda x:(x.addr1, x.addr2, x.addr3)

    def filterpackets(ip):
        for p in plist:
            try:
                c = getsrcdst(p)
                if(ip in c[0]):
                    # server IP is source IP of packet
                    yield -1
                if(ip in c[1]):
                    # server IP is destination IP of packet
                    yield 1
            except AttributeError:
                pass

print("This prints a measure of packets received to packets sent, using a moving average of %d packets."%(n))
print("0 indicates a perfect balance of sent-received.")
print("+1 indicates all packets are sent to the server.")
print("-1 indicates all packets are sent by the server.")
print("A larger positive number indicates an unresponsive server.")

count = 0
for pack in filterpackets(server_ip):
    d.append(pack)
    count += 1
    if(count>n):
        print("%0.4f"%(sum(d)/(1.0*n)))


print_attack_measure("1.pcap") # sem ataques
print_attack_measure("2.pcap") # com ataques
```

A função lambda extrai os IPs de origem e destino do pacote.

pacote enviado ao servidor : +1 pacote enviado pelo servidor : -1

O código está em http://pastebin.com/DFEnZzqn

Erro: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYHbw.jpg

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Estás a tentar aceder a n fora da função mas este só é visível dentro da função experimenta declarar o n fora da função, antes de esta ser chamada, ou colocas esse print dentro da função

Comment: @Miguel: Modifiquei um pouco -> novo código: http://pastebin.com/MRPwe8H6

Erro: http://imgur.com/a/0xiNt

O calculo dos pacotes está dando sempre 0.000!

Comment: @Miguel, que achas?

Comment: Ed o mesmo erro continua? Experimenta `n=30` mesmo antes do print

Comment: @Miguel:Mudou o problema: novo código: http://pastebin.com/MRPwe8H6


Erro: http://imgur.com/a/0xiNt

O calculo dos pacotes está dando sempre 0.000!

Comment: Não será porque estás só a filtrar IPv6? O print lá diz qualquer coisa a ver com isso

Comment: @Miguel, não! a msg é do scapy! Aparece em todo programa ->http://imgur.com/a/naBuW

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55408/discussion-between-miguel-and-ed-s).